# Treeshake bootstrap CSS with rollup(plugin)

Tags: javascript, css, bundler, tree-shaking

I am trying to remove unused CSS from my code, but I am struggling with tree-shaking my CSS files.

I decided to use rollup instead of webpack, because it was said that tree-shaking is a core idea behind the library, but now it seems to me that rollup is not capable of tree-shaking CSS files at all.

What I am doing is the following:

1. I create a rollup config for my page:

```
export default [
  {
    input: "path/to/index.js",
    output: [
      {
        format: "esm",
        file: "path/to/output/index.min.js",
      },
    ],
    treeshake: true,
    plugins: [
      postcss({
        extract: true,
        plugins: [cssnano()],
        extensions: [".css"],
      }),
      resolve(),
      commonjs(),
      terser(),
    ],
  },
```

Then I have my `index.js` file where I import my CSS and my JS:

```
import "../path/bootstrap.css";
import "../path/css/nav.css";
import "../path/css/footer.css";
import "bootstrap/js/dist/carousel";

import "../modules/css/example.css/";

import { example_function } from "../path/to/js/example.js";
example_function();
```

I run the rollup bundler and it creates a minified JS and a minified CSS file. So far so good, but it still includes the complete bootstrap classes for the CSS. I would like to tree-shake the **CSS** and only include the classes that are actually used.

Are there some settings that I am missing? Or is this not as easyly possible as I hope to achieve it.

Comment: I managed with rollup and purgeCSS. If anyone is interested how, let me know in the comments and I'll provide an answer

Comment: Yes please share your solution

Comment: @shadow why would you ask? if you have a solution just post it as an answer already.

Comment: @SumitWadhwa I waited because my time is limited and if no one needs it I rather save my time. Also, please watch your tone.

Answer (score 2):

What I ended up doing:

1. Installed postcss plugin
2. Added `postcss.config.js`
3. Added the following code to treeshake

```
const purgecss = require("@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss");

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    purgecss({
      content: ["./**/*.html"],
    }),
  ],
};
```

Hope it helps